# Dont deselect a selected row in view based NStableview when clicked outside

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

In my view based NSTableView i don't want to deselect the selected cell, when clicking in an empty part of the NSTableView, **how to obey this default behavior**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Improved version** from **Neha's answer** (this obeys the select / deselect)

Subclass NSTableView and implement :

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSPoint globalLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    NSPoint localLocation = [self convertPoint:globalLocation fromView:nil];
    NSInteger clickedRow = [self rowAtPoint:localLocation];

    if(clickedRow != -1) {
        [super mouseDown:theEvent];
    }
}
```

We just ignore the event, when we don't hit a row...

Comment: Great, +1 for the improvement :)

Answer (score 2):

Implement the mouse down event of your NSTableView by subclassing it. Inside it check if the clicked point is a row or empty area. If it is an empty area, then again select the previously  selected rows of your table view.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
NSPoint globalLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
NSPoint localLocation = [self convertPoint:globalLocation fromView:nil];
NSInteger clickedRow = [self rowAtPoint:localLocation];

NSIndexSet* selectedRows = [self selectedRowIndexes];
NSLog(@"%ld",clickedRow);
[super mouseDown:theEvent];

if(clickedRow == -1)
{
    [self selectRowIndexes:selectedRows byExtendingSelection:NO];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This the Swift4 version if anyone needs it:

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    let globalLocation = event.locationInWindow
    let localLocation = convert(globalLocation, from: nil)
    let clickedRow = row(at: localLocation)

    if clickedRow != -1 {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
    }
}
```